# Mouse wheel event difference

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, mousewheel

### Please look at the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var scrollFunc=function(e){
    var direct=0;
    e=e || window.event;

    if(e.wheelDelta){//IE/Opera/Chrome 
        userMouse(e.wheelDelta);
    }else if(e.detail){//Firefox
        userMouse(e.wheelDelta);
    }
}

if(document.addEventListener){
    document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll',scrollFunc,false);
}//W3C

window.onmousewheel=document.onmousewheel=scrollFunc;//IE/Opera/Chrome/Safari

function userMouse(flage){
    if(flage == 3){
        alert("firefox UP！");
    }else if(flage == -3){
        alert("firefox DOWN！");
    }else if(flage == 120){
        alert("IE UP！");
    }else if(flage == -120){
        alert("IE DOWN！");
    }
}
</script>
```

The question is: if I roll the mouse wheel once,it will alert once in Firefox,but twice in IE/Chrome/Opera.I think it's kernel problem,right?How can I resolve it?

Comment: Why do you want to resolve it? What kind of resolution you want? If you want to debounce the function, why don't you?

Comment: Why is it tagged jQuery when you're using none?

Comment: I'm sorry I leaved for twenty minutes.I have used the jquery-1.8.1.js,only I didn't write it.And what I want to resolve is the mousewheel roll once,the event be implemented once.

Comment: Can you listen to scroll events instead of mousewheel events?

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vEyw7/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your culprit:

`window.onmousewheel=document.onmousewheel=scrollFunc;`

In IE, Chrome, Opera, and Safari, you're handling the `onmousewheel` event for both the `document` and the `window`.

You only see one alert in Firefox because, you're only handling the `document`'s `onmousewheel` event here, on this line:

```
 if(document.addEventListener){
      document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll',scrollFunc,false);
 }
```